# SQL server: Inserting a bunch of rows into a table, generating a "batch id" for every 100?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inserting a bunch of rows into another table, and watch to generate an unique batch id for every X rows inserted (in this case X will be 100 or so).

So if I'm inserting 1000 rows, the first 100 rows will have batch_id = 1, the next 100 will have batch_id = 2, etc.

```
INSERT INTO BatchTable(batch_id, col1)
SELECT batchId, col1 //how to generate batchId???
FROM OtherTable
```

Comment: I would do the `INSERT`, then do an `UPDATE`.

Comment: How would you update batchId then?

Comment: Leave it `NULL`, then do an `UPDATE` using a `CTE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can take advantage of integer division here for a simple way to round up to the next 100:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col1, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) FROM dbo.OtherTable
)
--INSERT dbo.BatchTable(batch_id, col1)
SELECT batch_id = (99+rn)/100, col1 FROM x;
```

When you're happy with the output, uncomment the `INSERT`...

Comment: what if I needed to insert col1, col2, and col3 into the table as well? Does it matter if it's (ORDER BY col1)?

Comment: @Henley only you can answer that. Do you want your batches enumerated in any specific order? If so, then use that to ORDER BY. If not, then no, it doesn't matter. You just need to add the other columns to the inner and outer queries. (Next time, please ask a full question instead of dumbing it down to exclude some details that are obviously important to you.)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Hmm.. what if I want batch_id to increment from a number? So if the max batch id is 100, then the next time I do the insert, the batch id starts with 101?

Comment: @Henley then use `SELECT batch_id = 100 + (99+rn)/100, ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `row_number()` function:

```
declare @batchGroup int = 100

Insert into BatchTable(batch_id, col1)
Select ((row_number() over (order by col1)-1)/@batchGroup)+ 1 As batch_id, col1
From OtherTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO BatchTable (
    batch_id
  , col1
)
SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY somecolumn)) - 1) / 100 + 1
      , col1 
FROM OtherTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO BATCHTABLE 
            (BATCH_ID, 
             COL1) 
SELECT 1 + ( ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER( 
                 ORDER BY COL1) ) / 100 AS batchId, 
       COL1 
FROM   OTHERTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I ran into this same situation.  In my case, however, introducing any kind of ORDER BY prevented parallelism and caused indexes to be missed or an expensive SORT step to be introduced to the query plan.

In my table, I have an integer unique key column (call it account_id) and I didn't care about the ordering of the batches or having an exact size of each individual batch, but I needed there to be batches numbered sequentially (say 1 - 100) broken up more-or-less evenly across the entire set of rows, so I did this instead:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (batch_id, account_id)
SELECT (account_id / 100) + 1, account_id 
FROM Account_Table
```

As time goes on and data grows, I may need to change the 100 to 1000 or 10000 or whatever, but for my case that was the easiest / cheapest way to accomplish the task.

Edit: Changed % (mod) to / (integer division), sorry for any confusion.